# Prevent account from being created twice by double clicking

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an app that uses the MEAN stack, recently I have seen a little strange behaviour. Now this doesn't happen every time a user registers, so far it has happened 3 times. When a user registers the app creates 2 accounts for that user with all the same details. Now I have already added functionality to detect if a user already exists with that email and redirect them towards the login page but doesnt seem to stopping the issue.

Heres my code:

```
// =========================================================================
// LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        firstNameField: 'firstName',
        lastNameField: 'lastName',
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        jobTitleField: 'jobTitle',
        startDateField: 'startDate',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // check to see if theres already a user with that email
            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'That email is already taken.'
                });
            }
            else { var token = crypto.randomBytes().toString();
                  // if there is no user with that email
                  // create the user
                  var newUser = new User();

                 // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
                newUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
                newUser.email = email;
                newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password); // use the generateHash function in our user model
                newUser.jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;
                newUser.startDate = req.body.startDate;
                newUser.birthday = req.body.birthday;
                newUser.region = req.body.region;
                newUser.sector = req.body.sector;
                newUser.accountConfirmationToken = token;
                newUser.accountConfirmationTokenExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
                newUser.accountVerified = 'false';
                newUser.isLineManager = 'false';

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;
                    else {

                        var data = {
                            from: 'system',
                            to: email,
                            subject: 'Account Verification',
                            text: 'You recently registered onto the App, to gain access to your account please verify your account.\n\n' +
                                'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
                                'http://' + req.headers.host + '/verify/' + token + '\n\n'
                        };

                        mailgun.messages().send(data, function(error, body) {
                            console.log(body);
                            console.log("setting token 1");
                            req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + email + ' with further instructions.');
                        });
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    }));
```

**My Conclusions:**

I tested the app by creating a test account and once I had filled out the signup form I quickly **clicked twice** on the signup-now button and when I checked the database it had created 2 accounts with the same details. Basically it sends 2 POST requests to create accounts and both of them get approved. When only 1 should be approved.

**My Question:**

1. How can I fix this issue so if the user clicks twice on the signup
   button it only creates one account.
2. Also could there be another reason this might be happening, is there
       any issue with the code above?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

App Config Code:

```
// configuration ===============================================================


mongoose.connect(database.url);                                 // connect to mongoDB database on modulus.io
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));  // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(busboy());
app.use(compression()); //use compression
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': true}));             // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());                                        // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');                                  // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: ''})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());                                    // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash());                                               // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
```

**Edit:**

Route code:

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        return res.json({
            message: 'An account with this email is already registered. Please try to login, if you cant remeber the password then please use our password reset service'
        })
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        return res.json({
            redirectUrl: '/verifyAccount',
            message: 'We have sent an email to verify your email. Once you have verified your account you will be able to login'
        });
    });
})(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Issue must be due to asynchronous operations with db in node.js. Check your flow , use callbacks

Comment: Can you please post your `middleware` code also? (where you have your `app.configure` block)

Comment: @DavidR you mean the code in my `server.js` file where I configure the whole app? or the middleware route that calls the `local-signup` function?

Comment: I mean the `server.js` where you have all your app configurations.

Comment: @DavidR please see the updated question

Comment: Hmm.. You have placed everything in the right order there..

Comment: hmm .. I made some changes to the route that calls `local-signup` could the issue be there? I can't seem to see it.

Comment: Can you please check if any other request is going twice in your network panel?

Comment: @DavidR I just tested a data entry feature in my app and double clicking there too generates duplicate data and there are 2 log entires in the console panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the signup button on first press to prevent double click on it.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't fix the main issue in the code. Thats only a work around.

Comment: I know. I do not know nodejs but the only thing which comes into my mind is to try to lock the database writing when your app starts processing first request or use transactions

Answer (score 0):

1. As a solution I can advice you to set `unique constraint` on your `email` column, that won't to allow to insert rows with an existing email
2. And what about the code that uses LocalStrategy, it should work correctly, but you can just override `usernameField`, `passwordField`(So, you can remove other fields). Use `req.body` in order to get other form data as you've already done (Just in case of refactoring)